# How to debug geth with goland?

Tags: ethereum

I would like to be able to debug through Geth's Go code - using Goland.

It looks to me as if the entry point for Geth is main.go, however, when I try to run this I get the following errors:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/codet/go #gosetup
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/6t/tdn_s_2x2rx1scn774cwvlph0000gn/T/___geth_go -gcflags "all=-N -l" /Users/codet/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/main.go #gosetup
# command-line-arguments
cmd/geth/main.go:136:3: undefined: configFileFlag
cmd/geth/main.go:177:3: undefined: initCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:178:3: undefined: importCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:179:3: undefined: exportCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:180:3: undefined: importPreimagesCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:181:3: undefined: exportPreimagesCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:182:3: undefined: copydbCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:183:3: undefined: removedbCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:184:3: undefined: dumpCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:186:3: undefined: monitorCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:186:3: too many errors

Compilation finished with exit code 2
```

I add debug point to function main, but it didn't work.

```
func main() {
    if err := app.Run(os.Args); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, try this command `go build -x path-to-go-ethereum/cmd/geth/*go`, you will see what happens with flag -x. Should compile the package instead.
In goland, right click the geth folder, just choose run->go bulid, you will get what you expect.